# Sequelize generated columns sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sequelize.js

my table in `sqlite` has four columns a, b, c, d.

the value in `c` is `a-b` and `d` is `a+b` .

i define my model like

```
const myModel = sequelize.define('mymodel', {a:Sequelize.INTEGER,b:Sequelize.INTEGER,c:Sequelize.INTEGER,d:Sequelize.INTEGER}
```

and create an object like

```
var myModelObj = {a:10, b:20, c:function(){return this.a - this.b}, d:function(){return this.a + this.b}
```

and then create data in db like

```
myModel.create(myModelObj);
```

When i am doing like this, its fine. But i am looking for a way that i can define the value generators of c, d in the model definition itself. Is there a way of doing it.

Comment: Maybe using [Getters & Setters](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/docs/models-definition/#getters-setters)?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [in the docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-definition.html#getters--amp--setters) you can define getters and setters

```
const myModel = sequelize.define(
  'mymodel',
  {
    a:Sequelize.INTEGER,
    b:Sequelize.INTEGER,
    c: {
      Sequelize.INTEGER,
      get() {
        const a = this.getDataValue('a');
        const b = this.getDataValue('b');
        return a-b;
      },
      set() {
        const a = this.getDataValue('a');
        const b = this.getDataValue('b');
        return a-b;
      },
    },
    d: {
      Sequelize.INTEGER,
      get() {
        const a = this.getDataValue('a');
        const b = this.getDataValue('b');
        return a+b;
      },
      set() {
        const a = this.getDataValue('a');
        const b = this.getDataValue('b');
        return a+b;
      },
    },
  }
);
```